# Add link to image with <a href /> already set?

Tags: javascript

I am new to all this and stuck on the following;

I have a banner slider on the home page set as follows;

```
<li><a class="thumb"  href="img/index1.jpg" ><img src="img/sliderImg1.jpg" /></a></li>
<li><a class="thumb"  href="img/index2.jpg" ><img src="img/sliderImg2.jpg" /> </a></li>
<li><a class="thumb"  href="img/index3.jpg" ><img src="img/sliderImg3.jpg" /></a></li>
```

I want visitors to be able to click on the href="img...." and be directed to a specific page.

I can't work out how this is possible, any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: what happens when user click on the image

Answer (score 0):

Change `<a class="thumb"  href="img/index1.jpg">` so the href attribute contains the URL of the page you want the visitor to go to.

All else being equal, that is all you need to do.

Since you mention you are using a slider, it is possible that your slider script will interfere. We don't have the code to it though, so can't say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
 <a href="YourURL"><img src="image_source"/></a>
```

Check w3schools.com for more information & "try it yourself" pages on HTML.

Comment: Anything against it? I found it pretty useful... If you have any other preferred site for tutorials, please let me (& others) know. :)

Comment: Oh ok... I used it only as a crash course or learn in 24 hrs type course. But yes, I agree, that it is incomplete in many sense.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to specify the `URL` you want to the user to be directed to in the `HREF` tag of the `A`nchor element. Like this:

```
<li><a class="thumb" href="http://www.google.com" ><img src="img/sliderImg1.jpg" /></a></li>
<li><a class="thumb" href="http://www.facebook.com"><img src="img/sliderImg2.jpg" /> </a></li>
<li><a class="thumb" href="http://www.yahoo.com" ><img src="img/sliderImg3.jpg" /></a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your page url in href, like these examples below...

```
<li><a class="thumb"  href="www.yoururl.com/1" ><img src="img/sliderImg1.jpg" /></a></li>
<li><a class="thumb"  href="url/url2.html" ><img src="img/sliderImg2.jpg" /> </a></li>
<li><a class="thumb"  href="folder/image.jpg" ><img src="img/sliderImg3.jpg" /></a></li>
```